# React-router get optional query parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i have been looking into some examples on stack overflow for defining optional query params in react-router and finally found out that it can be done like

```
 {
    path: '/forms/simulacao/:journeyId?',
    exact: true,
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
    authRequired: true
  }
```

so at next step i want to retrive the query param that is "journyeId" if it is there, so i tried with

```
const history=useHistory()
console.log(history.location)
```

but that doesn't seems to work, what should be the workaround for this ??

> "react-router": "^5.1.2",
> "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a hook for this: useParams from react-router-dom

```
<Route path="/item/:id" component={NewsPage} />
```

After that, in NewsPage component I will be able to grab an ID from route like this:

```
const params = useParams()
fetchNews(params.id).then(data => setNews(data))
```

And so on

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to export component with router

```
export default withRouter(MyComp);
```

Then you'll have matching parameter in props

```
let {journeyId} = props.match.param;
```

Your complete component will be

```
const MyComp = (props)=>{
    let {journeyId} = props.match.param;

    return ...
}
export default withRouter(MyComp);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `:journeyId` is part of your route and not a query parameter. Query parameters should be defined like path: '/forms/simulacao?journeyId=something',

Something like this,

https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters